# Load years in ASP.Net DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, datetime-format, dropdownbox

I need to fill my DropDownList with years but I'm struggling with it. I tried doing it for months and succeeded. The problem is I am having issues in calling the right methods for the DateTime object. Can somebody help me out?

Here is how I have loaded months in my DropDownList:

```
Sub LoadMonth()
     Try
         ddlMonth.Items.Clear()
         If ddlMonth.Items.Count = 0 Then
            For month As Integer = 1 To 12
                Dim monthName As String = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(month)
                ddlMonth.Items.Add(New ListItem(monthName, month.ToString("00")))
            Next
        End If
        ddlMonth.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", 1))
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What's actually the problem?

Comment: I need to know how can I call the right methods to load years from system just like I have done with months

Comment: u just want to show list with  years like say 2010,2011...upto some 2100 like that??

Comment: @akhilkumar Starting from 2008 upto 2100

Comment: What is making a "year" different to a normal number for you?

Comment: Please give me some hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve it using a loop like:

```
  Dim i as integer
  for  i = 2008 to 2100
    ddlYear.Items.Add(i.ToString());
   next i 
  ddlYear.Items.FindByValue(System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()).Selected = true;  //set current year as selected
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this, may be help full for you:

```
 Dim myList As New List(Of Integer)
 myList.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1950, 100).Reverse())
 ddlYear.DataSource = myList
 ddlYear.DataBind()
 ddlYear.Items.FindByValue(System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine, thanks.

```
 private void LoadYears()
    {
        int i;
        
        for (i = 2019; i <= 2125; i++)
        {
            cb_Years.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            cb_Years.Items.FindByValue(System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
        }
        string strYear = System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        cb_Years.Items.Insert(0, new ListEditItem(strYear, Convert.ToString(0)));
        cb_Years.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```